# Swift's Array type is bridged to Foundation's NSArray class, how?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) we read the following:

> Swift’s Array type is bridged to Foundation’s NSArray class.

How can Swift's `Array` be bridged to Foundation's `NSArray` class when the first is a *value type* and the latter is a *reference type*? Doesn't bridging mean having an interface in a language to use a code in a different language?

Comment: In one of the WWDC videos there is a short description how the bridging `Array` <-> `NSArray` works under the hood.

Comment: Thank you @vadian, I think you don't have a link to that video. I'll try to search for it and post it here if I found it.

Comment: As far as I can remember the video is about Swift and value types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value/reference distinction here is a bit of a red herring.

Bridging is (maybe surprisingly) straightforward. There's an internal protocol, [`_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/ca5c65f93ca8f89ccb51fac41a225081490d5f23/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift), that describes a type which can be cast between an ObjC and a Swift type. The compiler replaces, e.g., your `mySwiftArray as NSArray` with a call to `_bridgeToObjectiveC()`.

You can see [`Array`'s conformance to the protocol](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Array.swift) in Foundation. It's simple Swift code: each method just constructs an instance of the appropriate bridged type.

So there's not really any relation to the fact that the native Swift `Array` is a value type.

As for that piece; while externally a "value", `Swift.Array` actually has an internal *pointer* to its own storage. If you think about it for a second, this is the only sensible way to make it work. You don't want to be moving the 101 things in an array every time you assign it to a new variable. Just a nice quick copy of a pointer. (Of course you need [to do the copy if you want to *change* something](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/struct-semantics-in-swift/), but it's delayed as long as possible.)

You can see basically the same behavior in a C struct with a field that's a reference to some allocated memory:

```
typedef struct _Array {
    void * payload;
} Array;

Array c;
c.payload = malloc( /* Whatever */ );
Array d = c;
```

Assigning to `d` makes a copy of the *pointer* to the storage, but there's only one chunk of allocated memory, which hasn't moved or been copied. (And to extend this backwards, you can "bridge" this to `NSArray` in the same way `Swift.Array` does: by providing an appropriate function that does the transformation.)

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We can reason how this is might be supported without watching a video, though do that as well!

> Doesn't bridging mean having an interface in a language to use a code in a different language?

Well a bridge in general is just a means of connection...

> How can Swift's Array be bridged to Foundation's NSArray class when the first is a value type and the latter is a reference type?

... which doesn't preclude conversion as part of the process.

To subclass an `NSArray` just requires overriding two methods `count` and `objectAtIndex:`. To bridge a Swift array to an Objective-C one a subclass of `NSArray` can be defined which contains (a copy of) the Swift array, i.e. stored in an instance variable.

This subclass would implement the two required Objective-C methods in terms of the corresponding methods on the wrapped Swift array, doing any additional processing necessary; e.g. during indexing to wrap a Swift value as an opaque Objective-C object or convert it to a corresponding Objective-C object. Such a process would be "lazy", individual elements in the Swift array only being converted to Objective-C objects when, and if, they are accessed. Once converted values can be cached to avoid re-conversion.

The actual implementation will be optimised and probably take advantage of private information. However as the above shows there is nothing to prevent a bridge presenting a value type in Swift as a reference type in Objective-C, and vice-versa.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. But Swift's `Array` is `struct`, so it can't be a subclass of `NSArray`. `Array` initializer initializes it on the stack because it's a `struct`, while `NSArray` initializes its instances to be located on the heap and give back a pointer to them. The internals of them are really very different and I still don't understand how was the bridging made despite your explanation. Thank you again for your explanation.

Comment: It doesn't matter that Swift's array is a value type. You write, say, `@interface MySwiftArrayWrapper : NSArray` and it *wraps* the Swift array. If that doesn't make sense consider a class instance variable of type `double`, a value type, now just change `double` to `Array`.